# variable inside XML tag to a column in R data frame

Tags: r, xml, xml2

Trying to convert XML file to a data frame in R.However the XML tag(node) have the same name twice for one single customer. I want that each node in a seperate column in a dataframe.

```
<Consumer ConsumerOID="123">
<BillingContact>
        <PhoneInformation Type="Main">
        <PhoneNumber>4758796523</PhoneNumber>
      </PhoneInformation>
      <PhoneInformation Type="Home">
        <PhoneNumber>1234567890</PhoneNumber>
      </PhoneInformation>
</BillingContact>
</Consumer>
<Consumer ConsumerOID="256">
<BillingContact>
        <PhoneInformation Type="Main">
        <PhoneNumber>9856321475</PhoneNumber>
      </PhoneInformation>
</BillingContact>
</Consumer>
```

```
library(XML)

doc<-xmlParse("test.xml")
step1 <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes=getNodeSet(doc,"//OCADocument/Consumer/BillingContact/PhoneInformation"))
```

the above code gives me only phone number and that to in a single column in a dataframe. This makes it difficult to identify which  phone number belong to which consumerOID.

I want output in a dataframe format as shown below

```
"ConsumerID      Phonenumber1       Phonenumber2"
"  123           4758796523         1234567890"
"  256           9856321475         NA"
```

Comment: Why do you want wide format? Nearly every analysis works better with long format.

Comment: Parfait, i want each tags in a different column so that it can be used further by the team when required. However, the way xml tags are structured i am not able to get them separately as the tags have same name. Hope this answers your question.